# 'FailedExecution' error when executing workitem

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Prior to the changes to the Engine version, my design automation for Inventor app was working fine. After changing to a newer Engine version, I have started to get error when executing the workitems. The reason I changed the engine was because my workitem for newer inventor files (> 2018) are not processed but those that are from 2018 and older were working fine.

So, I changed 'Autodesk.Inventor+23' to 'Autodesk.Inventor+24' and even to 'Autodesk.Inventor+2021' (current). After that, all my workitems are running into "FailedExecution" Error.

Here are the WorkItem details:

- workitem Id : f4ff1446ac994007a8cfe3ba565caabf

My guess is the my addin is not loading correctly, but I am not sure how to verify that. Any help in finding the cause of the issue is appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The reason my Design Automation app for Inventor was not loading is because when I changed the 'engine version' of my app to a later version than 2018, the .addin xml file must have the below entry [See here the snapshot of the .addin file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmIVr.png):

```
<SupportedSoftwareVersionLessThan>27..<SupportedSoftwareVersionLessThan>
```

In previous versions, this was not mandatory. So, after I added this entry, then the addin gets loaded and my workitem continued to execute correctly like before. I don't see the 'FailedExecution' error anymore.